# Extract an external dynamic link using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm not sure if this will be possible, but is there any way to extract the dynamic link under this webpage: http://www.mobileonline.tv/channel.php?n=69111 the dynamic link is named "Link 1 (HLS): not compatible with all channels" thanks

Comment: You need to show us what you've tried before we can help you. Why should we try to help someone who's not put any thought into a solution already, even if it's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, besides xss, the only easy way is by

1. going to that page,
2. right clicking on that link,
3. click on inspect element.

The anchor tag should be highlighted for you in the developer tool. You can find the url in the href attribute of the anchor tag.